# Doppler Effect - Moving Wave Source

Tags: animate, pst-plot, multido, pst-calculate

Could someone help me animate (\usepackage{pst-plot, pst-calculate, multido, animate}, preferably) a wave-point source moving with uniform speed v (the first variable) and emitting concentric wave-fronts of frequency f (the second variable)? The phase velocity of the wave is constant c. An example ("The Doppler effect with a moving source" - animation) is given in https://www.animations.physics.unsw.edu.au/jw/doppler.htm#source? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: There are several images and animations. Do have you tried something with `\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-calculate,multido,animate}`?

Comment: Yep, the animation with \begin{animateinline} would be ideal.